# How to correctly deploy a dotnet lambda layer with AWS CDK?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy an AppSync API with multiple lambda function data sources. Common functionality between these functions will be housed in lambda layers.

Upon running `cdk deploy` however, everything works fine until the first function that uses a layer is being packaged:

```
... invoking 'dotnet publish', working folder '/asset-input/bin/Release/net6.0/publish'
... dotnet publish --output "/asset-input/bin/Release/net6.0/publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "net6.0" /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false
... publish: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
... publish: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
... publish:   Determining projects to restore...
... publish:   Skipping project "/XCoreLayer/src/XCoreLayer.csproj" because it was not found.
... publish:   Skipping project "/XCoreLayer/src/XCoreLayer.csproj" because it was not found.
... publish:   Restored /asset-input/XHandler.csproj (in 1.31 sec).
... publish: /var/lang/bin/sdk/6.0.301/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2066,5): warning : The referenced project '../../XCoreLayer/src/XCoreLayer.csproj' does not exist. [/asset-input/XHandler.csproj]
```

I understand that the XCoreLayer project file was not included in the build container for XHandler, as the code used to define the lambda is as follows:

```
var XHandler = new Function(this, "XHandler", new FunctionProps
    {
        FunctionName = id + "-XHandler",
        Runtime = ResourceProperties.dotnetRuntime,
        Handler = "XHandler::XHandler.Function::FunctionHandler",
        MemorySize = ResourceProperties.defaultLambdaMemorySize,
        Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME", props.lookUpTable.TableName },
            { "META_TABLE_NAME", props.metaTable.TableName },
            { "MAIN_USER_POOL_ID", props.mainUserPool.UserPoolId }
        },
        Layers = new[] { coreLambdaLayer },
        Code = Code.FromAsset("./src/lambda/XHandler/src", new Amazon.CDK.AWS.S3.Assets.AssetOptions
        {
            Bundling = new BundlingOptions
            {
                Image = ResourceProperties.dotnetRuntime.BundlingImage,
                Command = new[] {
                    "bash", "-c", string.Join(" && ", ResourceProperties.defaultLambdaPackagingCommands)
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Could someone let me know how to include the XCoreLayer project into the build image (without including the layer code in the build)?

For more context, here is the definition of the layer in CDK:

```
var coreLambdaLayer = new LayerVersion(this, "CoreLayer", new LayerVersionProps
    {
        RemovalPolicy = RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        CompatibleRuntimes = new[] { ResourceProperties.dotnetRuntime },
        Code = Code.FromAsset("./src/lambda/XCoreLayer/src"),
    });
```

And the packaging commands for the lambda:

```
public static readonly string[] defaultLambdaPackagingCommands = new string[]
    {
        "cd /asset-input",
        "export DOTNET_CLI_HOME=\"/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME\"",
        "export PATH=\"$PATH:/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_HOME/.dotnet/tools\"",
        "dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools",
        "dotnet lambda package -o output.zip",
        "unzip -o -d /asset-output output.zip"
    };
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm curious what it is you are including in your shared layer code? And how you are then loading that in your function code? I'm assuming reflection of some kind.

Comment: Hi James. This core layer contains all models/interfaces used throughout the applications, as well as some database helper methods. I am loading the layer project as a ProjectReference in the functions that use them. The frustrating thing is that it works smoothly in another SAM app I developed.

Comment: Despite what the documentation shows, I do not believe the `fromAsset` function actually bundles code properly for a Layer (for a function, yes, but not a layer). I have only had success with `AssetCode` method instead and pointing to a zip. It does mean an extra step - i use a makefile to generate the zip of the layer before deployment - but I have not either been able to make `fromAsset` work

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. I'm just curious now. When you compile the function, that will also compile the referenced project. When you then create the code bundle do you go through and remove the shared DLL's to be then loaded from the layer? Because as a default the shared libraries would be included in the function bundle, which removes the need for the layer.

Comment: Thanks @lynkfox and plantpowerjames. Indeed I plan to remove the DLLs after packaging. So for now it seems I'd have to include the built layer package in the lambda build containers and then remove it after building. I'll type it into an answer after implementing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm intrigued to see this working and how you load the DLL's from the layer at runtime. It would be great if you could share a complete code sample when it's working and any performance impact of dynamically loading DLL's from a layer.